# Why the docker container is not start with command 'docker start container_name' when create with command 'docker run container_name'

Tags: docker

When we create the container with the following command:

`docker run -it --name dev ubuntu`

It creates and runs in the fore + background.

Similarly, when we want to create the container but only want to make the container run in the background not in the foreground then we use the following command:

`docker run -d --name dev ubuntu tail -f /dev/null`

Now the question is when the container is created with any of the above commands then the container can be started with the command:
`docker start dev`

But if we create the container with the command:
`docker run --name dev ubuntu`

Then the container is created and stopped immediately (**I know this is the default behavior**). But there is no way to start such a container.

I tried this command to start the container by this command:
`docker start dev`

But not start the container. I also tried the Docker Desktop to start this container, but it was not working.

Comment: `docker run` will always start from a clean state, and in many routine cases you need to delete and recreate a container to change a basic setting.  I'd recommend always using `docker rm; docker run` to recreate a container, and avoiding `docker start` in most cases.  The container you show running `tail -f /dev/null` as its process doesn't do anything, and you can probably skip creating the container entirely.

Comment: My question is how to start the container if it is created by using the command docker run ubuntu

Comment: `docker run` starts the container already, you don't need to separately `docker start` it.  The plain `ubuntu` image isn't that interesting and for most uses you'll want to write a Dockerfile (potentially starting `FROM ubuntu`) to install some actual application into the image.

Comment: `docker run ubuntu` does not start the container it only creates the container which will immediately stop.